# Calculating counts when working with elements using name/value pairs

Tags: xslt

I have an xml in this format. I am looking to generate an output in the output format given below.

I am trying to calculate the total number of SkuID's associated with each unique SerialNum. The same SerialNum can be present more than once within the xml. Could you please suggest how I can get the count in this scenario?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <root>
        <Skid>
            <NameValuePairs>
                <NameValue>
                    <ID>SerialNum</ID>
                    <Value>12345678</Value>
                </NameValue>
                <NameValue>
                    <ID>calcTotals</ID>
                    <Value>true</Value>
                </NameValue>            
            </NameValuePairs>
            <Box>
                <SkuID>5729305323</SkuID>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <SkuID>2334923423</SkuID>
            </Box>
        </Skid>
        <Skid>
            <NameValuePairs>
                <NameValue>
                    <ID>SerialNum</ID>
                    <Value>22334455</Value>
                </NameValue>
                <NameValue>
                    <ID>calcTotals</ID>
                    <Value>true</Value>
                </NameValue>            
            </NameValuePairs>
            <Box>
                <SkuID>42342234234</SkuID>
            </Box>
            <Box>
                <SkuID>3243325352</SkuID>
            </Box>
        </Skid>
        <Skid>
        <NameValuePairs>
            <NameValue>
                <ID>SerialNum</ID>
                <Value>12345678</Value>
            </NameValue>
            <NameValue>
                <ID>calcTotals</ID>
                <Value>true</Value>
            </NameValue>        
        </NameValuePairs>
        <Box>
            <SkuID>75547453333</SkuID>
        </Box>
        <Box>
            <SkuID>235356233266</SkuID>
            </Box>
        </Skid>
    </root>
```

Output:

```
     <Skids>
          <Box>
             <TrackingNumber>12345678</TrackingNumber>
             <Total>4</Total>
          </Box>
          <Box>
             <TrackingNumber>22334455</TrackingNumber>
             <Total>2</Total>
          </Box>
       </Skids>
```

Comment: @Rupesh_Kr pointed out in an edit that some of your XML is malformed due to opening and closing tags not matching, or closing tags begin missing.

Answer (score 1):

Using **XSLT 2.0** with for-each-group

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

   <xsl:template match="root">
       <Skids>
           <xsl:for-each-group select="Skid" group-by="NameValuePairs/NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value">
           <Box>
               <TrackingNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value"/></TrackingNumber>
                <Total><xsl:value-of select="count(current-group()//Box)"/></Total>
           </Box>
       </xsl:for-each-group>
       </Skids>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using **XSLT 1.0** with Muenchian Method

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output indent="yes"/>    

  <xsl:key name="Tracking" match="Skid" use=".//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
       <Skids>
           <xsl:for-each select="Skid[generate-id() = generate-id(key('Tracking', .//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value))]" >
           <Box>
               <TrackingNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value"/></TrackingNumber>
               <Total><xsl:value-of select="count(//Skid[.//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value = current()//NameValue[ID='SerialNum']/Value]//Box)"/></Total>
           </Box>
       </xsl:for-each>
       </Skids>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<Skids>
   <Box>
      <TrackingNumber>12345678</TrackingNumber>
      <Total>4</Total>
   </Box>
   <Box>
      <TrackingNumber>22334455</TrackingNumber>
      <Total>2</Total>
   </Box>
</Skids>
```

Answer (score 1):

The first part of my solution is a temporary variable, named `ids`,
and containing (no surprise) `ID` elements.

Each of them contains content of a `Value` element, which has `ID` sibling
with `SerialNum` content.

Additionally, this `ID` element has `cnt` attribute - the number of `SkuID`
elements in the "current" `Skid`.

Then `ID` elements in this variable are processed in a *for-each-group* loop,
grouping them by the content (ID value).

So the whole script looks like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="root">
    <Skids>
      <xsl:variable name="ids">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Value[../ID = 'SerialNum']">
          <ID>
            <xsl:attribute name="cnt" select="count(../../../Box/SkuID)"/>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </ID>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:variable>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$ids"/>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="$ids/ID" group-by=".">
        <Box>
          <ID><xsl:value-of select="."/></ID>
          <Total><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/@cnt)"/></Total>
        </Box>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </Skids>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Note: `<xsl:copy-of select="$ids"/>` instruction was placed for
demonstration purpose only. In the final version remove it.